# "what is <a> charset attribute and why it does not supported in HTML5?"

Tags: html

As a newbie in the programming world, I started to learn basic stuff and got stuck with this charset attribute in HTML. Help me to figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very hard to tell what you're asking, but if you mean that you've see an `<a>` tag that looks something like this - `<a href="someURL" charset="UTF-16">`, then it means that the link is specifying that the page it is linking to has different character encoding than the document it is linking from.